# Backup Exec 10 - Network connection to the remote agent has been lost

Tags: backupexec

Okay, so I have 4 remote offices, all running off of a 3mb ethernet connection.  Two sites are part of a WAN and 2 sites are using 3mb connections over a site to site tunnel.

I am using Backup Exec 2010, I have the remote agent installed on all the remote servers.  For the past few weeks now, on the two sites running over the site to site tunnel have been failing with the following error message now.

"The network connection to the Backup Exec Remote Agent has been lost.  Check for network errors"

We used to be on a DSL connection site to site tunnel, now we changed to the 3mb ethernet connection using site to site tunnel.  I have to find out, has it been failing ever since we changed, or just recently.

Backup exec support is telling me it is a network issue.  My communication or connection to the server is solid, we don't have any issues, or outages.  So I am baffled on why this continues to fail.  And why just those two sites..

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run wireshark or tcpdump on the Backup Exec Server and the server with the Remote Agent and log everything.  Then compare when Backup Exec says you dropped the connection with what Wireshark/tcpdump shows at that same time?